# How to get Result type from ControllerContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to get the Action result type (`ViewResult`, `JsonResult`, etc) from an instance of `ControllerContext`?

Comment: Where is your code running? An ActionFilter?

Comment: This is running in FilterConfig where I'm wiring up global filters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The controller runs much earlier than any ActionResults. But if you are writing an ActionFilter you could get that information from the `filterContext` using its Result property.

For example:

```
public class MyGlobalActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result;
        if (result is ViewResultBase)
        {
            // the controller action returned a view result 
            // (either a ViewResult or PartialViewResult)
        }
        else if (result is JsonResult)
        {
            // the controller action returned a JSON result
        }
        else if (result is RedirectToRouteResult)
        {
            // the controller action redirected
        }
        .... and so on
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that this makes sense only once the controller action has finished executing, a.k.a only inside `OnActionExecuted`, `OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted`. It makes no sense to be attempting to verify what result did the controller action returned before this action has finished executing.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I didn't think so but wanted to make sure.  I'm not trying to verify a result.  Just trying to verify the Result type.